# Define styles to elements immediately before and after another element CSS

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have been searching for the past hour to find the correct CSS Selector (or at least to find out if one exists) to style the elements in the DOM immediately before and after another element.

At the moment, I have a `ul` whose `li` elements have a `border-bottom` property. I would like to change the colour of that border if there is an element immediately after it in the DOM. If possible, I would like to avoid using separate classes for this.

Consider the following markup:

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item 1</li>
    <li>List Item 2</li>
    <li>List Item 3</li>
    <li class="divider">2</li>
    <li>List Item 4</li>
    <li>etc.</li>
</ul>
```

I would like to add `border-bottom: none` to `<li>List Item 3</li>` and any other `li` elements that are immediately followed by `li.divider`.

Is there are a CSS selector for this, something like `ul > li`, but for this? It doesn't need to be cross-browser, and can be CSS3; just needs to work on WebKit browsers...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

this is not possible. there is no css selector for preceding elements; neither preceding siblings, nor ancestors.

you can, however, apply a style to the next (and only the next) sibling:

```
li.divider + li {border:1px solid black}
```

you can chain it. this style:

```
li.predivider {border-bottom: none} /*before*/
li.predivider + li {border:1px solid black} /*divider*/
li.predivider + li + li {border-bottom: none} /*after*/
```

and this (combinable):

```
li.divider {border:1px solid black} /*divider*/
li.divider + li {border-bottom: none} /*after*/
```

allows you to apply just one of either the “predivider” class, or the “divider” class, dependent of the divider being the first element (and thus has none before it) or not.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Too bad CSS doesn't support this. Any idea if I could do it using Sizzle?

Comment: @BenM: Sizzle doesn't provide a preceding sibling selector either, but if you're using jQuery with Sizzle then you can use the `.prev()` and `.next()` methods to find the previous and next siblings.

Comment: what he said. xpath can do all this, but unfortunately, you can’t specify stylesheets with xpath selectors, only css :(

Comment: @flying sheep: You can with XSL/XSLT (that's what XPath was designed for), not CSS.

Comment: @Bolt: writing XML(-like) syntax for the document markup is awful enough, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

`.divider + li` to select to immidiate sibling `<li>` to `.divider`.

As for the one before it, I don't think it's possible (please correct me if I'm wrong)